# How to cleanly send data between .NET Core and .NET Framework apps, serializing with Json.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, .net-core, json.net

I am communicating between a .NET Core 3.1 (+ .NET Standard 2.1) app and a .NET Framework 4.6 app, both of which I have total control over. The .NET Core launches the .NET Framework process, and these two processes talk to each other over a redirected stdout/stdin.

My .NET Core app (Core) wants to tell my .NET Framework app (FW) to run a method given some data.

The API it uses is something like `SendMessage("FW_MethodName", new List<object> { param1, param2 });` (This operation needs to happen in the FW process and FW doesn't know to do it until Core tells it to do it).

I use Json.NET for serialization and serialize the above message like so:

```
public class ATypeOfMessage : BaseMessage 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<object> Args { get; set; }

    public Message(string name, List<object> args) 
    {
        Name = name;
        Args = args;
    }
}

ATypeOfMessage message = new ATypeOfMessage("FW_MethodName", new List<object> { param1, param2 });
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandline = TypeNameHandling.All };
string serializedMessage = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message, typeof(BaseMessage), settings);
// the idea being that I have multiple types of messages, so I serialize/deserialize BaseMessages and
// save off $type metadata, so I can deserialize the string into the correct derived class (ATypeOfMessage)
myFWProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine(serializedMessage);
```

FW then reads the message:

```
string serializedMessage = Console.In.ReadLine();
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandline = TypeNameHandling.All };
BaseMessage message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BaseMessage>(serializedMessage, settings);

switch (message) 
{
    case ATypeOfMessage myMessage:
        // ATypeOfMessage is doubly-defined in FW and Core
        // get the methodInfo for method myMessage.Name and do...
        object answer = methodInfo.Invoke(this, myMessage.Args.ToArray());
        break;
}
```

This works fine for simple types (e.g. int, string), but the moment I pass in something more complex like `byte[]`, deserialization crashes.

This happens because the `$type` field that Json.NET saves off contains the assembly `System.Private.CoreLib`, which can't be access from FW.

I tried working around this by doing some assembly name redirecting using Json.NET's `SerializationBinder`:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandline = TypeNameHandling.All, SerializationBinder = new MySerializationBinder() };

class MySerializationBinder : DefaultSerializationBinder 
{
    public override void BindToName(Type serializedType, out string assemblyName, out string typeName) 
    {
        base.BindToName(serializedType, out assemblyName, out typeName);
        if (assemblyName.StartsWith("System.Private.CoreLib")) 
        {
            assemblyName = "mscorlib";
        }
    }
}
```

This is a bit hacky, and I'd prefer not to do it, but it works fine for more complex types, so I can do `SendMessage("FW_MethodName", new List<object> { byteArray, stringArray });`

However, even more complex types like `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` break. The `$type` data that's saved off is:

```
\"$type\":\"System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib],[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib]], System.Private.CoreLib]], mscorlib\",\"k1\":[\"a\",\"b\",\"c\"],\"k2\":[\"a\",\"b\",\"c\"],\"k3\":[\"a\",\"b\",\"c\"]
```

which contains CoreLib again, so FW is unable to deserialize it.

Another thing that I've tried is to amend `ATypeOfMessage` to accept a list of *strings* instead of objects, and then I do double serialization.

Core Serialization:

```
public SendMessage(string methodName, List<object> args) 
{
    List<string> serializedArgs = new List<string>();
    foreach (object arg in args) 
    {
        serializedArgs.Add(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(arg);
    }

    // ... same logic as before to create ATypeOfMessage, serialize the whole thing, and send it to FW
}
```

FW Deserialization:

```
// ... deserializes the object as before, but before invoking the method, we deserialize the specific args
MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(ClassWithMethods).GetMethod(myMessage.Name);
ParameterInfo[] paramInfo = methodInfo.GetParameters();
object[] finalParams = new object[myMessage.Args.Count];
for (int i = 0 ; i < myMessage.Args.Count; i++) 
{
    object arg = myMessage.Args[i];
    finalParameters[i] = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(arg, paramInfo[i].ParameterType);
}

object answer = methodInfo.Invoke(this, finalParameters);
```

This seems to work fine, but I'd prefer a method that doesn't involve double serializing each arg into a string. Is there such a method?

The last thing I tried was to not save off `$type` information for my args:

```
[JsonProperty(ItemTypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None)] 
public List<object> Args { get; set; }
```

Then when deserializing, the args become JObjects, JArrays, or JValues (all types of JTokens) as per the "Untyped Objects" section [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm).

And then when I deserialize and prepare to call the method, I convert my args like so:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < myMessage.Args.Count; i++) 
{
    object arg = msg.Args[i];
    if (arg is JToken)
    {
        arg = (arg as JToken).ToObject(paramInfo[i].ParameterType);
    }
    finalParameters[i] = arg;
}
```

Now, I have the opposite problem as before. The complex types (`string[]`, `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`) deserialize correctly, but a type like `byte[]` doesn't, because Json.NET turns the byte array into a base64-encoded string, and so when FW gets it, it doesn't know that the string should really be a byte array.

How can I cleanly send data like this between Core and FW? Maybe I need to use `JsonConverters` for something like this?

Comment: Any of the Network communication approaches would work. They are designed to work across OS, Programming languages, design patterns and any other possible barrier. So of course they would work for something as simple as Framework/Core Communication. | Of course depending on if they run on the same machine or even start one another, there might be even better IPC approaches. | You have not really told us what either of those two programms do. Are they in a client/server relationship? Peer to peer? Will those two have to communicate within the same network, or across the internet?

Comment: @Christopher communication modality is irrelevant. It's the serialization that's the issue here.

Comment: @Asti What is or is not relevant is up to pushkin to decide.

Comment: @Christopher Core launches the FW process. They're both on the same machine and network. I thought that serializing and writing to Stdin/Stdout would be the simplest approach

Comment: @Christopher Sorry I didn't mean to start an argument. I thought the discussion should be about solving his type serializing issue.

Comment: @Asti I always consider workarounds to Serialisation a solution. Especially as I do not know serialisation that much :)

Comment: @Christopher You're right :D. There are definitely nicer ways for doing RPC - which is what's being done here I think. Like using grpc - but that's not generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the double serialization over the args that I mentioned in my question. Didn't find any other reliable way of handling this:

.NET Core:

```
public SendMessage(string methodName, List<object> args) 
{
    List<string> serializedArgs = new List<string>();
    foreach (object arg in args) 
    {
        serializedArgs.Add(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(arg);
    }

    // ... same logic as before to create ATypeOfMessage, serialize the whole thing, and send it to FW
}
```

.NET Framework:

```
// ... deserializes the object as before, but before invoking the method, we deserialize the specific args
MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(ClassWithMethods).GetMethod(myMessage.Name);
ParameterInfo[] paramInfo = methodInfo.GetParameters();
object[] finalParams = new object[myMessage.Args.Count];
for (int i = 0 ; i < myMessage.Args.Count; i++) 
{
    object arg = myMessage.Args[i];
    finalParameters[i] = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(arg, paramInfo[i].ParameterType);
}

object answer = methodInfo.Invoke(this, finalParameters);
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that JSON.NET ignores the the `[TypeForwardedFrom]` attributes of relocated types, which is exactly for compatibility reason when types are serialized. In .NET Core every classic serializable framework type has this attribute with the old framework identity. For example: https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Dictionary.cs,35

**Solution 1:**

In your `MySerializationBinder` override the `BindToName` method:

```
public override void BindToName(Type serializedType, out string assemblyName, out string typeName)
{
    if (Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(serializedType, typeof(TypeForwardedFromAttribute), false) is TypeForwardedFromAttribute attr)
       assemblyName = attr.AssemblyFullName;

     // ...
}
```

Resolving types with old identity should work automatically by `Type.GetType` also in .NET Core/Standard

**Solution 2:**

If you communicate between .NET applications and are not enforced to use JSON serialization you can try [this `XmlSerializer`](https://docs.kgysoft.net/corelibraries/?topic=html/T_KGySoft_Serialization_Xml_XmlSerializer.htm), which ignores assembly names by default but if used with assembly qualified names, then it can consider the `TypeForwardedFromAttribute` ([nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/KGySoft.CoreLibraries/))

Comment: very interesting, didn't know about TypeForwardedFrom. Will play around with this

Comment: hmm, so the TypeForwardedFromAttribute code gets hit when my `Args` property is a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`, but not for simpler types like `byte[]`, so I'm forced to use the same `if (assemblyName.StartWith("System.Private.CoreLib") -> reassign to mscorlib` code. And even then, I get a crash deserializing, because the inner types in the dictionary still say System.Private.CoreLib

Comment: Actually you can completely ignore the assembly name if it is a core assembly because `Type.GetType` needs the assembly name for non-core types only. Arrays have element types (possibly nested: array of array), which makes things difficult, not mentioning possible complex generic type arguments from various assemblies. If you need a fully general solution for any serializable data I recommend the 2nd solution.

Answer (score -1):

I can not help with serialisation itself, only with way to get around needing it.

Since we have a case of one process (Core) starting the other (FW), they could actually communicate with Console Input Redirection. If you start a programm via the Process class (wich is the primary way anyway) and the other programm is a console or at least checks the streams, you can have them communicate that way: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput#remarks

While easier then Serialisation, it might not be as "future proof" as it. Later you may want something totally else being able to call the FrameWork App. Or you generally want it to be able to communicate via Networking.

Comment: I basically do exactly that (redirecting and writing to stdout/stdin) and WriteLine, but I need the other process to understand what the thing it's reading is. (I might pass classes over that need to be understood by FW), so I serialize to a string and write that and now need to deserialize on the other end

Comment: @pushkin Not quite. What you seem to be doing is adding the serialized data as Commandline Arguments. The ones that you can retreive in main by using the args[] array. Those are just DOS era commandline arguments, not imput redirection. They also have a rather short character limit.

Comment: I'm not using command line args at all. I just write to stdin from Core and read from stdin from FW. Maybe I didn't explain it clearly